# A clone-like file appears and disappears. Is it a virus?

Tags: windows-xp

Another semi-transparent file (like a copy) will appear every time I click open a Word or  Excel file. This file disappears when the Word or Excel file is closed.

How can I solve this problem and/or identify & remove this virus? I have already used antivirus programs to scan my computer (redi Avast & AVG Free).

Comment: Really? A virus? Quite certainly a temporary store: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;211632

Comment: @ta.speot.is: I'd rather give the OP the benefit of the doubt here. Perhaps he turned on Show hidden files by mistake and is seeing the temp copy for the first time.

Comment: Having two antivirus programs installed isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 6):

That's normal behavior. (You have your computer set to show hidden/system files.)

It's a temporary file that MS Office uses - not a virus.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211632

Answer (score 0):

This is normal functionality but it is not a virus, it is a temporary file and you probably have your PC to show hidden system files such as system32 files.
-hailey.sims